# Browse Code before and after a bug is fixed in a repository from GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

From GitHub's [Issue API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) we can get details of an issue including who closed the issue. Is there a way to browse the code(using commit ids or any others) before the particular issue has been fixed and browse the code after the issue has been fixed?

Ex: Say you have bug # 12 on version 1.2 of the code

I should be able to browse the code that has the bug #12(Ver 1.2) in it and also the code with the bug fixed, say Version 1.2.1

Thanks